# AWS Connect Start Outbound Call Keeps Calling Customer even when call is declined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I use StartOutboundVoiceContact to initiate a call to customer A. The call is connected to a flow that utilizes AWS Lex.

All is fine and working as expected. I also managed to get the transcript and recordings by integrating Kinesis Video Streams.

My issue is that if customer A declines/rejects the call, AWS Connect keeps calling again and again as long as the timeout of 60 seconds is not reached. This behavior is causing unnecessary calls and impacting the customer experience.

I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this call part of a campaign?

Comment: No, it is not. It could be a wrong SIP signal from the telephone provider (sending 403 Forbidden) Not sure!

Comment: Then TrafficType should be GENERAL and you shouldn't provide a campaign ID. Not saying you're doing so; just worth validating.

Comment: Yes sure! I am in a region that does not support campaigns anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the carrier!
You need to contact AWS support to open a case with the carrier to help you investigate the issue. In my case, the carrier updated the route to solve the issue.